# Avoiding Hard Coding to get Python file paths

Tags: python, operating-system

I am working on the files with different locations. I want to avoid hard coding at every step. My files Involves, Input files(consisting of inputs), python scripts and output files. Now, I want to interact with each of the mentioned folder without hard-coding my scripts. Does python has any module for trimming down the path to root directory and accessing the subsequent folders.

Currently, I am using os.getcwd() for accessing my script's path. I want to use the output of this code for accessing other files in the different folder

```
import os
dirpath = os.getcwd()
root_dirpath, py_script = os.path.split(dirpath)
```

root_dirpath in the code gives me the path for my python script. I want to trim this path to user folder and then access the file from the other folder. Is there any module to do this with out actually hard coding.

Comment: look in to `pathlib` from the stdlib as well as the `__file__` statement

Comment: `getcwd` only returns your script's directory if you run your code from that directory.

Comment: ```os.listdir(PATH)``` will list everything in the PATH, so you can loop through the contents of that. How many levels deep do you need to go from the root_dirpath?

Comment: @ekmcd I want to go 2 levels back. In "'os.listdir(PATH)''' do i need to specify the path! or is there a way to get the path for the root directory.

Comment: If by root dir/ user folder, you are referring to the home directory of the current user, then ```os.environ['HOME']``` should give you that. Then you can use ```os.listdir(os.environ['HOME']) ``` to list every file and sub_directory in ```os.environ['HOME']```

Comment: Thank you. - @ekmcd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is current-working-directory,
and then there is the directory your program is in.
They are distinct concepts, and might have the same value or different.

This expression is pretty useful:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Or more simply, just take dirname of [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) if your `$PYTHONPATH`
lacks troublesome entries like `..`

Some projects will have a "top" directory that is one or more levels up
from the location of your python source.
You might find it useful to append `'../../..'` to `__file__`,
or use `os.path.join()` to accomplish the same thing.

Here is one possibility for locating your favorite files:

```
from pathlib import Path

top = Path(__file__ + '../..').resolve()
arrow = top / 'assets/arrow.png'
print('source image:', arrow)
print('destination image:', top / 'output' / os.path.basename(arrow))
```

Caveat: sometimes library code runs directly from a .zip file
or other unusual environment.
In that case you might find `__file__` is not quite as useful.